# Multiple Slick carousels in modal overlays playing at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, carousel, slick.js

I have a page with a number of hidden Slick carousels.

To launch a carousel I'd like the user to click a related button and the corresponding slider would show in a modal with a semi-transparent background behind it.

However, when you launch any carousel on the page, all carousels are launched and can be seen autoplaying behind one another.

Here's my HTML:

```
<button class="launch-gallery">Launch gallery 1</button>
<div class="modal">
  <div class="img-gallery">
  <h2>Gallery 1</h2>
  <div class="img-gallery__slides">
    <div class="img-gallery__slide">
      <img src="image-1.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="img-gallery__slide">
      <img src="image-2.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<button class="launch-gallery">Launch gallery 2</button>
<div class="modal">
  <div class="img-gallery">
  <h2>Gallery 2</h2>
  <div class="img-gallery__slides">
    <div class="img-gallery__slide">
      <img src="image-3.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="img-gallery__slide">
      <img src="image-4.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's my JS to trigger the modal:

```
var $galleryModal = $('.modal');

$('.launch-gallery').click(function(){

    $galleryModal.toggleClass('is-open');

    return false;
});
```

Here's my Slick configuration:

```
var $imgGallery = $('.img-gallery__slides');

$imgGallery.slick({
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  dots: false,
  arrows: false,
  accessibility: false,
  cssEase: 'ease',
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 5000,
});
```

Is there a way to only launch the one carousel related to the button clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
$('.launch-gallery').click(function(){

$(this).next('.modal').toggleClass('is-open');

return false;
});
```

Comment: This works a treat. How would it work is if the button to launch the gallery was inside a number of child divs? Thanks!

Comment: if the button is somewhere else , then you can go with `data` attribute, like in the button add `data-target` and in the modal you can give id. for example `<button data-target="modal1" class="launch-gallery">Launch gallery 2</button>` and the the id of the modal should be like `<div id="modal1" class="modal">` , and store the target with `var $target = $(this).attr("target");'

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
var $galleryModal = $('.modal');

$('.launch-gallery').click(function(){

    $galleryModal.next('.modal').toggleClass('is-open');//open only the modal asociated to the button
    var $imgGallery = $(this).next('.modal').find('.img-gallery__slides');//get the gallery from that modal
$('.img-gallery__slides').slick('unslick');//destroy the other gallery 
$imgGallery.slick({
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  dots: false,
  arrows: false,
  accessibility: false,
  cssEase: 'ease',
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 5000,
});
    return false;
});
```